# Google analytics changes visitors

Tags: google-analytics, visitors

Yesterday 26 Feb. 2014 I noticed that Analytics stated that my total visits is about 350 visits. Today's, 27 Feb., morning I noticed that it recorded for the same day about 750 visits. Now, in the night, 27 Feb., it returned to 350 visits.

Is there any problem with my analytic code on my website? Or does it an issue with Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. That is odd. Google does funny things with GA and WMT from time to time and changes reporting as a result. I have seen changes from time to time myself. But not in the user count per day. I would bet it is a oddity with Google more than anything. I would make sure that the GA code on your site is up to date. Otherwise, I am not sure what else you can do.